# Filter dataframe rows by index name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame where I want to drop elements depending on their index name

```
               col1  col2
entry_1          10    11
entry_2_test     12    13
entry_3          14    15
entry_4_test     16    17
```

Basically I want to drop the ones ending with _test

I know how to select them:

```
df.filter(like='_test', axis=0)

               col1  col2
entry_2_test     12    13
entry_4_test     16    17
```

Then I can actually get those indexes:

```
df.filter(like='_test', axis=0).index

entry_2_test
entry_4_test
```

And finally I can drop those indexes and overwrite my dataframe with the filtered one.

```
df = df.drop(df.filter(like='_test', axis=0).index)
df

               col1  col2
entry_1          10    11
entry_3          14    15
```

My question is if this is the correct way of filtering or there's a more efficient dedicated function to do this?

Comment: `df = df[~df.index.str.endswith('_test')]` should do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can invert the result of `str.endswith`:

```
In[13]:
df.loc[~df.index.str.endswith('_test')]

Out[13]: 
         col1  col2
entry_1    10    11
entry_3    14    15
```

Alternatively slice the last 5 characters and do a comparison using `!=`:

```
In[13]:
df.loc[df.index.str[-5:]!='_test']

Out[18]: 
         col1  col2
entry_1    10    11
entry_3    14    15
```

It's still possible to use `filter` by passing a regex pattern to filter out the rows that don't end with `'_test'`:

```
In[25]:
df.filter(regex='.*[^_test]$', axis=0)

Out[25]: 
         col1  col2
entry_1    10    11
entry_3    14    15
```

As pointed out by @user3483203 it's better to use the following regex:

```
df.filter(regex='.*(?<!_test)$', axis=0)
```

Comment: @user3483203 sure will do

Answer (score 3):

With `filter` `regex`

```
df.filter(regex='.*[^_test]$', axis=0)
Out[274]: 
         col1  col2
entry_1    10    11
entry_3    14    15
```

Comment: I would recommend using `df.filter(regex='.*(?<!_test)$', axis=0)` instead, as the current regex will remove a row with index `entry_3_este`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension and feed a list of Boolean values to `pd.DataFrame.loc`.

While this may seem anti-pattern, it's actually more efficient as Pandas string methods are not particularly optimised:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit df2.loc[[i[-5:] == '_test' for i in df2.index]]    # 11.7 ms per loop
%timeit df2.loc[[i.endswith('_test') for i in df2.index]]  # 13.3 ms per loop
%timeit df2[~(df2.index.str[-5:] == '_test')]              # 22.1 ms per loop
%timeit df2[~df2.index.str.endswith('_test')]              # 21.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is very true, the `str` methods are depressingly slow compared to list comprehension +1